# how does linux kernel choose the right src ip when route packet?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, linux-kernel, route

I have a kubernetes cluster using Calico as CNI plugin. We can get some routes in my local route table like

```
root@k8s-master:~# ip r
default via 192.168.100.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.215 metric 100
10.222.235.232 dev cali5bda0fdd27a scope link  # route to pod
10.222.235.233 dev cali1209a63af2b scope link
10.222.235.235 dev cali12d4a061371 scope link
10.222.235.241 dev cali9d4dd01dda6 scope link
10.222.235.246 dev calid0a379e0710 scope link
10.222.235.248 dev cali67ee1300377 scope link
```

There are multi interfaces on my machine. I want to know how linux kernel choose the right src ip when route packets to pod?

```
root@k8s-master:~# ip r get 10.222.235.232
10.222.235.232 dev cali5bda0fdd27a src 192.168.200.2 uid 0
    cache
```

`cali5bda0fdd27a` interface doesn't have ip address. It is one end of veth pair in host network namespace(the other end is in container network namespace).

`192.168.200.2` is another interface's ip. Why does linux kernel choose `192.168.200.2` but not `192.168.100.215` ?

Comment: what interface has IP `192.168.200.2`? 
`192.168.100.215 ` is on interface `ens18`, traffic towards `10.222.235.232 ` is routed through interface `cali5bda0fdd27a`. 
Is that the interface with IP `192.168.200.2`?

Comment: interface `cali5bda0fdd27a` is one end of `veth pair` in host network namespace(the other end is in container network namespace). It doesn't have ip address. `192.168.200.2` and  `192.168.100.215` are two physical interfaces' ip address.

Comment: do you have a bridge interface on host, what interfaces are bridged with it? What is the IP on the bridge interface?

Comment: no bridge on host